# Docker : 'go.mod: permission denied' on go commands

Tags: linux, docker, go

I got an error

```
go: open /go/src/dummy/go.mod: permission denied
```

when i try to execute any **go command** in Docker (go get, go list etc.)

OS:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

docker:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c
```

image: golang:1.13.3-alpine3.10

to illustrate this, I created a dummy project

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print("this file is not important for question")
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.13.3-alpine3.10 as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/dummy
COPY . .
RUN go list
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

and empty files go.mod and go.sum, so now project dir is:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 curuser curuser 139 may 23 15:03 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 curuser curuser  22 may 23 15:03 go.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 curuser curuser   0 may 23 14:48 go.sum
-rw-r--r-- 1 curuser curuser  86 may 23 14:50 main.go
```

Build image, and i got:

```
$ docker build -t dummy ~/go/src/dummy
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/5 : FROM golang:1.13.3-alpine3.10 as builder
 ---> f23ef2e47d30
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /go/src/dummy
 ---> Running in 0e276917d658
Removing intermediate container 0e276917d658
 ---> e9e910dd0ccd
Step 3/5 : COPY . .
 ---> 19230669ad27
Step 4/5 : RUN go list
 ---> Running in faefa6d5930e
go: open /go/src/dummy/go.mod: permission denied
The command '/bin/sh -c go list' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Now I change a Dockerfile to stay alive (comment line 4 : # RUN go list)
so I can build and run image

```
$ docker build -t dummy ~/go/src/dummy
....
Successfully built 385e0629e67f
Successfully tagged dummy:latest
```

then I run sh in docker, and get permissions of copied files:

```
$ docker exec -it 6da5ca617c4d  sh
#-----now we in the docker-----
/go/src/dummy # ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           108 May 23 12:15 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            22 May 23 12:03 go.mod
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 May 23 11:48 go.sum
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            86 May 23 11:50 main.go
```

But even if i change now permissions for go.mod to 777
i still got the same error:

```
#-----in the docker-----
/go/src/dummy # chmod 777 go.mod
/go/src/dummy # go list
go: open /go/src/dummy/go.mod: permission denied
```

Same isssue on other versions of golang image (golang:1.13.11-alpine3.11 , 1.14.3-alpine3.11 etc.)

Same issue reproduces on real project, 
so I can't execute *go get*, *go list* etc. in docker.

Previously, everything worked fine, but at some moment (22.05.2020) this error appears without any changes in files or configuration

Please, help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colution was a complete reinstall of docker.
After reinstall (same version 19.03.6) all works fine.
Unfortunately, i could not find the reason and any other way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```sh
RUN go list
```

with

```sh
RUN ["chmod", "+rwx", "go list"]
```

> `+x` should also do. I mentioned `+rwx` to give an idea on how to set permissions explicitly. For `go list`: `+x` permission is just fine.

As you might be aware alpine based images have `sh` shell and not `bash`.

The default shell for RUN in Docker is `/bin/sh` and here the permissions are not being set correctly (Problem).

`RUN /bin/bash -c <command>` should also work but as alpine based images don't have bash out of the box, then the explicitly setting permission should help you!

Comment: If it doesn't work, try fixing it using `chown` and `chmod` in `RUN` explicitly in a single line using `&&` for your whole project.

Comment: i tried `RUN ["chmod", "+rwx", "go list"]` , but got  error `chmod: go list: No such file or directory` . Also, owner of go, sh and project files in container is root

Comment: Try:

`RUN ["chmod", "+rw", "/go/src/dummy/go.mod"] && go list`

Comment: unfortunately, all combinations of permission change commands have no any effect, all the files in image already have owner root

Answer (score 0):

```
go: open /go/src/dummy/go.mod: permission denied
```

The path starting with /go seems to refer to a docker volume. The permission error might have happened due to root user usage while running previous images and the creation of volumes. My advice is to prune both images and volumes and download all docker images and run from scratch. After executing the following commands, the application should work correctly.

```
docker image prune -a
docker volume prune
```

Reinstallation of docker should also work, but this is shorter.